# FFmpeg image2 output: Control JPG image quality when using mjpeg_qsv

Tags: ffmpeg, mjpeg

My FFmpeg command ouputs a series of JPG images. Simplified:

> ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 25 -i "video=My
> Webcam" -qscale:v 5 -vcodec mjpeg_qsv "C:\out\%d.jpg"

I want to use `-vcodec mjpeg_qsv` to leverage GPU acceleration. Usually (without "_qsv") I can control JPG image quality by using `qscale:v` , but it seems to have no effect in combination with mjpeg_qsv.

Is it even possible to control JPG image quality when using mjpeg_qsv? If yes, any ideas how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mjpeg_qsv encoder makes use of the `global_quality` option. Range is 1 to 100. Default is 80.

Comment: Side note, found out while testing this: When setting the (misplaced) qscale parameter as mentioned in the question, FFmpeg seems to set the global_quality value to 100